# Fireplace Crack between Brick and Drywall

Tags: drywall, fireplace, crack

Recently bought a house and today noticed a bit of a crack running vertically along where the fireplace bricks meet the drywall. Also there is some paint cracking on the ceiling right above (maybe old water damage?). This is on the first floor and above crack on the ceiling its the attic and roof.

Keep in mind I live in Austin,TX :)

Can I just use caulking to fill the gap or is there something else going on?

[image]

Comment: Age of the house?  Any other cracks in the house?  Anew house of 5 years or less might be just a settlement crack, but I have read some Texas soils are not nice to houses.